# Where is my datetime() function?

Tags: matlab

Matlab R2014b on Windows 7 64 bit. The [documentation refers to a function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) `datetime` that I am clearly missing:

```
>> datetime
Undefined function or variable 'datetime'.
>> which datetime
'datetime' not found.
>> version
ans =
    8.3.0.532 (R2014a)
```

Is this a know issue, and if yes, is there a workaround?

Comment: what sort of licence are you using? Chances are that your licence file might be corrupted. `datetime` is a primitive MATLAB type, but still requires the presence of a valid standalone licence/group/FLEXnet licence in your system.

Comment: The `datetime` type is new to R2014b.  The version you're apparently using is "`8.3.0.532 (R2014a)`".  Make sure you are actually starting an instance of R2014b instead of R2014a if you have both installed.

Comment: @TroyHaskin Ah, silly me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data type `datetime` appears from R2014b

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/date-and-time-operations.html

Comment: Ah, the version was right there before my eyes all the time! Thanks!